# Remove HTML via clicking Browser Action after adding it to DOM in Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

I want to create something like [Font Face Ninja](https://fontface.ninja) where I click on the browser action & it loads a UI & after clicking again it removes the UI.

My minimal reproduction is as follows -

## manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample Extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {},
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "https://*/*", "http://*/*"]
}
```

## content.js

```
const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

const div = document.createElement('div')
div.innerHTML = `<h1>Sample Extension</h1>`
body.appendChild(div)
```

## background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: 'content.js',
  })
})
```

The above example appends `<h1>Sample Extension</h1>` to any page. This is my UI.

I want to remove that when browser action is clicked again. How do I do that?

Comment: Give that div an `id` like for example `chrome.runtime.id` and then just delete it in your content.js if it exists, otherwise add it.

Comment: I did the exact thing I think. It inserts & removes from DOM separately but while message passing its not working. Here's my follow up question → https://stackoverflow.com/q/57177357/6141587. I'm trying to figure it out from yesterday but no solutions yet.

Comment: @wOxxOm I found the solution which works. Thank you for all your help 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML can be removed easily by doing `body.removeChild(div)` in `content.js`.

However, I wanted it togglable which must be done using message passing so I posted a solution to make it togglable so it adds HTML to the DOM when clicked once & removes it when clicked again & so on.

Find the solution here → https://stackoverflow.com/a/57179116/6141587

I've also uploaded the repo containing both **Browser Action** & **Page Action** (check branch *page_action*) to Github → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/insert-remove-ui-chrome-extension/