# Chrome extension message passing is not working?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

In `contentScript.js` the function is not called.

## background.js

```
var insertUI = true
// var hasExecutedOnce = false

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  console.log(`clicked browserAction`)

  // if (!hasExecutedOnce)
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
    file: 'contentScript.js',
  })

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    from: 'background',
    subject: insertUI ? 'insertUI' : 'removeUI',
  })

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.subject === 'doneRemovingUI') insertUI = false
    else if (request.subject === 'doneInsertingUI') insertUI = true
  })

  insertUI = !insertUI
  // hasExecutedOnce = true
})

console.log(`bg`)
```

## manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample Extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "19": "icon19.png",
    "24": "icon24.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "38": "icon38.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "64": "icon64.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon19.png",
      "38": "icon38.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

## contentScript.js

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

function insertUI() {
  console.log(`insertUI`)

  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.setAttribute('id', 'sample-extension-12345')
  div.innerHTML = `<h1>Sample Extension</h1>`
  body.appendChild(div)
}

function removeUI() {
  console.log(`removeUI`)

  var divId = document.getElementById('sample-extension-12345')
  body.removeChild(divId)
}

function main() {
  console.log(`main called`)

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log({ msg, sender, sendResponse })

    if (msg.subject === 'insertUI') {
      insertUI()
      sendResponse({
        from: 'content',
        subject: 'doneInsertingUI',
      })
    } else if (msg.subject === 'removeUI') {
      removeUI()
      sendResponse({
        from: 'content',
        subject: 'doneRemovingUI',
      })
    }
  })
}
console.log(`contentScript`)

main()
```

So everything works. `insertUI()` & `removeUI()` works individually in `contentScript.js` but the `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` is never called.

The `console.log()` in it are not called. Rest everything works. Inserting in DOM & removing DOM works separately. They just need to work when `browser_action` is toggled.

Comment: To send a message from the background script to a content script you have to use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`, not `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`. Also, you have to  send the message after the content script has run, that is, in the callback function of `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. Finally, semicolons.

Comment: So I changed everything as you specified and it works. However, now I have a problem of multiple inserts & removals from DOM because `executeScript` adds the script every time I click the `browser_action`. How do I solve this problem? Here's the complete gist https://gist.github.com/deadcoder0904/ac26007a86e3a57846125446bf6c5227

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I have also added the solution as an answer altho technically it has its own problems. Check the answer below too since I've added screenshots of what's not working. It also keeps on adding nodes in DOM & removing them. If you know how to sovle this, it'd be of great help :)

Comment: okay found a solution finally that works perfectly. posting it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Iván Nokonoko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3930351/iv%c3%a1n-nokonoko) answered the problem above in comments. Posting it here for brevity -

## background.js

```
var hasExecutedOnce = false

function addUI(tabId) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
    from: 'background',
    subject: 'isUIAdded?',
  })
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  if (!hasExecutedOnce) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(
      tab.id,
      {
        file: 'contentScript.js',
      },
      function() {
        addUI(tab.id)
      },
    )
    hasExecutedOnce = true
  }
  addUI(tab.id)
})
```

## manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Sample Extension",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "19": "icon19.png",
    "24": "icon24.png",
    "32": "icon32.png",
    "38": "icon38.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "64": "icon64.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "icon19.png",
      "38": "icon38.png"
    }
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "<all_urls>"]
}
```

## contentScript.js

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]

function insertUI() {
  var div = document.createElement('div')
  div.setAttribute('id', 'sample-extension-12345')
  div.innerHTML = `<h1>Sample Extension</h1>`
  body.appendChild(div)
}

function removeUI() {
  document.getElementById('sample-extension-12345').remove()
}

function main() {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.subject === 'isUIAdded?') {
      const id = document.getElementById('sample-extension-12345')
      if (id === null) insertUI()
      else removeUI()
    }
  })
}

main()
```